# Maven: validation phase invoked 3 times

Tags: maven, plugins

I have written a maven plugin to create documentation from latex.
Now I added some verification and to that end
added another execution, the one with id `validate-converters` like so:

```
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>process-latex-sources</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>cfg</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>clear-latex-sources</id>
        <goals>
              <goal>clr</goal>
            </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>validate-converters</id>
        <goals>
              <goal>vrs</goal>
            </goals>
        <configuration>
          <versionsWarnOnly>true</versionsWarnOnly>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
```

Now the strange thing is, that for `mvn site` verification is run 3(!!!) times and I cannot figure out why.
I am willing to give you all code or anything to find out...

Comment: I have also noticed in the past that the maven site plugin likes to call phases again that have already run. I actually don't know why yet. I would try to make your plugin idempotent.

Comment: Hello Fabian, I dont know how to make it idempotent... Does a plugin know in which phase it has been used during a run??? How can I find out?

Comment: @Fabian: I think making idempotent is a workaround. Better to inform the guys developing the site-plugin. I was not even aware that site phase implies validation.

Comment: @Fabian: it is strange that validate is not predecessor of phase site. so why does this phase occur at all?? How do you know that the site plugin is the reason for calling my plugin???

Comment: If your LaTeX plugin creates files, it could check whether these files already exist before creating them again. For the site plugin: I haven't really looked into this deeper. I guess some reports require that certain phases have run before and therefore the site plugin triggers these phases.

Comment: no, it does not create files, this goal is just a check and emits warnings if appropriate. Also files have the disadvantage, that i would have to remove them later again...